# QGIS second-order district coloring

Tags: qgis, color

Is it possible to make a single layer style similar to what the map below has?

I.e. first-order districts have different hues, but their constituent second-order districts have different shades.

I'd rather not use the workaround of splitting the 1st-order districts into their own layers, since I'm working on a map with somewhere around 150 districts.

[image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hungary_1941-44_Administrative_Map.png]

example map: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hungary_1941-44_Administrative_Map.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the map that you are referring in your question is composed of of two layers: one with categorized color and the other one with gradient color, then using blending mode, you can get the effect that you see in your example map.

If you have the first and second orders are located in the same layer, you need to style the first order with categorized color (give each first order district a different color) and then make duplicate of the same layer and style the second order with graduated color (color ramp from light to dark color).

I don't think there is a way to style the same layer with categorized and gradient color at the same time.

For example, I have a map that shows the countries that I styled them using categorized color and I chose the name of the country to give me a different color for each country

[image]

I duplicated the layer to choose another field and I style it with gradient color

[image]

Then I applied a `Multiply` layer blending mode and `Overlay` feature blending mode, as you can see in the image above, and I chose an outline of light gray color.

Here is the output with blending mode applied:

[image]

Without using the blending mode above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. For the shading I used the _Coloring a Map_ plugin, which finds out the 4-color theorem for cells.

What I also found in QGIS 2.14 Essen was Layer Properties > Style > Rule-based > **Refine selected rules**, which allows additional/secondary styling.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means automatic, but when I have to do something like this, I set up a field (can be in a separate table that is joined to the original) with a code that is used for coloring. Then I can assign colors to specific codes. To code both first and second order, could do something like 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D for one hue, 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D for the next, etc. No need to a create new layers.

Note that theoretically you should not need more than [four hues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) for first-order district colors, not the (at least) six in the above example. For the second-order districts, you could leverage color ramps or something to get the colors within the hue.